# Combining imageView and TextView in a List

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi I am developing an app in android where I use a subclass that extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. Right now I have problem to combine `ImageView` and `TextView` in the list that is showing. Yesterday I found this link on stackoverflow that helped me to make this combination.

*[Overlay text over imageview in framelayout programmatically - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706913/overlay-text-over-imageview-in-framelayout-progrmatically-android)*

So it works FINE! - until I click on a listItem. The app chrash and the logcat tells me that
`"android.widget.RelativeLayout" cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView.` This exception comes the  `getGroupView()` in the class that extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter` . Why does this happen? (`RelativeLayout` extends `View`).

Am I completely on the wrong way when I try to return a `RelativeLayout` instead of an `ImageView`?

Here's my code from `getGroupView` (I'm a bit messy because I am in a teststate) :

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ImageView row = (ImageView) convertView;

RelativeLayout rLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
  LayoutParams rlParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
            ,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
    rLayout.setLayoutParams(rlParams);


if(row == null) {

    row = new ImageView(mContext);
}

row.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

row.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);


RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
tParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
TextView text=new TextView(mContext); 
text.setText("GOLDEN Gate"); 
text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);                            
text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
text.setLayoutParams(tParams);



rLayout.addView(row);
rLayout.addView(text);

return rLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `ImageView row = (ImageView) convertView;` gives the exception because u r trying to convert the `RelativeLayout` to `ImageView`.

You must return the `convertView` in `getViewGroup()` method but you are returning the RelativeLayout i.e., `return rLayout;`

**Solution :**

Add a `ImageView` and `TextView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Set that layout for ListItem by inflating it inside getView() method and assign the inflated layout to convertView. Return the convertView in getView() method;

Comment: thanks, I was also thinking in that direction but thought there was a possibility to make a cast somehow .. maybe to Object??? But I solved it now by using  LayoutInflater and putting imageview and textview in an xml-file.